# Using a Team Site as the target site when building a SharePoint App in Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365-developer

I always thought that you had to use the Developer Site Template for the site you used for debugging when building a SharePoint App. I just tried on two different machines using VS 2015, 2013 and 2012 and I was able to run and debug a SharePoint-Hosted App that targeted a Team Site in a SharePoint 2013 on-prem environment. I got an "Sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site" error when I tried to do the same thing against a Team Site in SharePoint Online. Anyone know what the difference is?

**Please note,** I'm not asking how I can use a Team Site instead of a Developer Site in SharePoint Online, I'm asking why there is a difference in the way Visual Studio deploys apps between SharePoint on-prem and SharePoint Online and ideally, what that difference is.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best reference on this is here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/12/10/enable-app-sideloading-in-your-non-developer-site-collection/

Basically, there is a method called at the site collection to determine whether side loading is turned on.

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AppCatalog.IsAppSideloadingEnabled

For SharePoint online, you will need to enable it.

You might double check your local environments and see if the feature is already enabled there.

Enable-SPFeature e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085 -url http://yoururl.com

Maybe it was already enabled on your local site collections?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I've read that post but it doesn't answer my question. In SharePoint 2013, 2016, and SharePoint Online, the sideloading Feature is off by default in the Team Site template. That being the case, I should get the "Sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site" error when I try to use a Team Site for debugging in all three environments. Yet I only get that error when the Team Site is in SharePoint Online. So there must be some difference in the way that Visual Studio deploys apps to SharePoint on-prem and SharePoint Online.